# How did Feynman derive this formula for the current of particles in a gas?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, diffusion

Feynman Lectures. Lecture 43. [Lecture Summary](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_43.html). The setting is that we are considering molecular motion in a gas near equilibrium.

> $\text{The current of particles / area sec.} = - \frac{1}{3}lv\frac{dn_a}{dx} = - \mu kT\frac{dn_a}{dx} = - D\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{n_a}{n_0}).$

Here, $D$ is the diffusion constant, $\mu$ the mobility, $k$ the Boltzmann constant, $T$ the temperature,$l$ the mean free path, $v$ the actual molecular velocity (mean), and $n_a$ as a function $n_a(x,y,z)$ the number density of special molecules in a small volume element centered on $(x,y,z)$.
$n_0$ is an unknown constant, variable or function, probably the total number density (special + background molecules in unit volume) where a
*special molecule* responds to the field and a *background molecule* doesn't respond on the field.

Can you show how he got $\frac{n_a}{n_0}$? In Lecture 43 he wrote $D = \tfrac{1}{3}lv$, $D = \mu kT$, but never $D = \mu kT \cdot n_0$.

At the beginning of the Lecture 43 there is the photo of a blackboard, on which Feynman was writing the summary (http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/img/FLP_I/f43-00/f43-00.jpg but you can browse the image directly only after going to feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_43.html).
On the blackboard in 6th line (also in Ch. 43-2) Feynman writes that $n_0$ means the total number of particles per unit volume. But in Ch. 43-5 there is formula $n_a = n_0e^{-U/kT}$. This is the exponential probability multiplicator and $n_0$ is the density at zero energy when the field is present (according to Lecture 40, ch. 40-1). So in the context of Ch. 43-5 $n_0$ means the number of special particles per unit volume at zero energy. I assume that there must be absolutely different number density of "background" particles (Feynman's term). Actually I am not sure what Feynman means by $n_0$ in different cases. Besides, the formula in the 9th line looks strange, because there was no $n_0$ at first.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably overthinking this and it is probably an error. Note that there is a very generic "transport equation" $$\frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t} + (\vec v\cdot\nabla)\rho = -\nabla\cdot J + \Phi,$$ 
which says, if you've never seen it before, "a box of volume $dV$ flows downstream in a fluid moving with velocity field $\vec v$, the time rate of change of stuff $\rho~dV$ in the box is equal to the divergence of the flow of the stuff in general $J$ plus the rate $\Phi$ at which stuff is magically entering the box out of nowhere".

The diffusion constants $D$ occur in this expression usually due to something like $J = -D~\nabla \rho$ and hence for constant $D$ they have the rough pattern $\dot \rho = D~\nabla^2 \rho,$ meaning that they have a sort of universal pattern of units, $[[D]] = \text{m}^2/\text s.$ While Feynman makes things confusing with his "one unit of area" this is probably also what he intends for the ultimate units of $D.$ Whenever you see this pattern of units you should wonder at whether it has some relationship to transport; the most famous case is that the kinematic viscosity $\nu/\rho$ happens to have these units and turns out to be a diffusion constant $D$ for momentum, which of course is conserved and therefore qualifies as a "stuff" for the transport equation to work on.

Now: given $n_a = n_0 e^{-U/kT}$ we have that $e^\text{anything}$ is dimensionless and hence $n_a/n_0$ is dimensionless, hence the SI units of the right-hand side are $(\text{m}^2/\text s)/\text m = \text m / \text s.$ This is inconsistent with his claim of it having units $\text{something}/(\text m^2 ~\text s)$ and is therefore dimensionally incorrect. Probably the $n_0$ is in error and he just meant to reprise the equation $-D~\frac{dn_a}{dx}$ or some such.

So, I mean, Feynman was wrong. There's nothing wrong with that; he sometimes is. We all sometimes write stupid crap on a blackboard and our students don't correct us. It's presumably because we raise them in a society where misunderstanding is somehow viewed with negative moral valence, you were 'wrong' and therefore 'you should be punished.' So it's not like his students were going to correct him.

Comment: Thank you. I saw some errors in summaries of previous lectures. But here he wrote $\tfrac{d}{dx}$, so he remembered about $dx$. It's not like a mistake made through lack of attention.